# Upload multiple images to database. Use react, express and axios to upload and retrieve images

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to upload multiple images to my react app.
I am using express in the backendd and axios for post and get the images.
I am also using mysql database to upload the image to and getting them from here.

I think I am close, but can't figure out whats wrong.
I only achieve the "error" message in the console, and the image src get the value of null.
I get the message "success" in the backend, and the images does get uploaded in the correct folder.
I have tried to watch tutorials as well exploring stack overflow, but can't figure it out. Can someone help?

Here is my code:

Frontend:

```
export function Media() {
  const [files, setFile] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/media")
  .then(res =>  {
    console.log(res.data)
    setFile(res.data)})
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}, [])
    
const setimgfile = (e) => {
  setFile(e.target.files)
}
    
const addUserData = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
    
  var formData = new FormData();
    
  for (const file of files) {
    formData.append('files', file)
  }
    
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  }
    
  const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/media", formData, config)
  
  
  if (res.data.status === 201) {
    console.log("NO error")
  } else {
    console.log("error")
  }
}

const fileList = files ? [...files] : [];

return (
<div style={{ padding: 15, backgroundColor: '#fff', marginTop: 15 }}>
  <h4>Upload file:</h4>
  <input type="file" name='photo' onChange={setimgfile} multiple />
  <button onClick={addUserData}>submit</button>
  <ul>
        {fileList.map((file, i) => (
          console.log(file),
          <li key={i}>
            <img src={"http://localhost:3000/images/"+file.image} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
</div>
)
}
export default Media
```

And here is my backend

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue: false

})) 
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.static("public"));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "./public/images")
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
}).array("files")

app.get("/media", (req, res) => {
    const sqlMedia = "SELECT * FROM media"

    db.query(sqlMedia, (err, result) => {
        if(err) return res.json(err)
        return res.json(result)
    })
})

app.post('/media', upload, (req, res) => {
    console.log('success')
    console.log(req.files);
     const image = req.files.filename;

    const sqlImage = "INSERT INTO media (image) VALUES (?)"
    db.query(sqlImage, [image], (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.json({message: "Error uploading image"})
        } else {
            return res.json({message: "Success"})
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: You can remove the content-type request header. It's unnecessary and incomplete

Comment: `req.files` is an array so `req.files.filename` will be `undefined`. You need to loop over it

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I had a problem "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client", but solved it by removing the last res.json in my code.